# Showing prev/next post links doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I have blog which is in sub directory and showing last post on static index page on main site.

main site -> http://example.com
blog -> http://example.com/wp

The blog post is showed correctly on main site but I can't show links for prev and next post/article. This is what I have an what I'm trying

```
<?php
        define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
        require('wp/wp-blog-header.php');

        $posts = get_posts('numberposts=1&order=ASC&orderby=post_title');
        foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?> 
        </h1><h2><?php the_date(); echo "<br />";?></h2>
        <h3><?php the_content(); ?> </h3>
        <div class="navigation"><p><?php posts_nav_link(); ?></p></div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

So this isn't visible: `<div class="navigation"><p><?php posts_nav_link(); ?></p></div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Layman language it is a wordpress function to fetch posts/custom-posts. Internally it calls WP_Query function. Or you can use WP_Query instead of this. 'posts_nav_link' function does not work with WP_Query & get_posts function. You can try this to get next previous links.

```
    $posts = get_posts('numberposts=1&order=ASC&orderby=post_title');
    foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?> 
    </h1><h2><?php the_date(); echo "<br />";?></h2>
    <h3><?php the_content(); ?> </h3>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <div class="navigation">
        <p><?php previous_post_link(); ?><?php next_post_link(); ?></p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I cant comment you because I haven't enough reputations,
First follow https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts link 
then check the sample code.

and also check the post display setting in the wp-admin panel /wp-admin/options-reading.php settings->reading section.